# AOSP sdk_car_portrait failed

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I use `lunch` command and select `sdk_car_portrait_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug` but i got these errors.

```
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:389:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:350:
In file included from build/make/core/product_config.mk:234:
device/generic/car/sdk_car_portrait_x86_64.mk:36: error:  build/make/target/product/sdk_phone_x86_64.mk does not exist..
17:08:28 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
```

Comment: Please mention the branch/tag you are using, it will be helpful for other users to help you debug it further.